# Apex actionSupport example doesnt work. 401 Unauthorized error for FileNotFound destination

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, actionsupport

I'm trying to create simple Ajax request using `apex:actionSupport` exact like [described in official documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm).

But on the client side it is looks pretty strange:

```
<form id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/knowledgebase/FileNotFound" method="post" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59">
    <input type="hidden" value="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59">
    <span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:counter" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59',event,{'status':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:counterStatus','similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:j_id61','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:j_id61':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:j_id61'} } )">Click Me!: 0</span>
    <span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:counterStatus">
        <span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:counterStatus.start" style="display: none"> (incrementing...)</span>
        <span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:counterStatus.stop"> (done)</span>
    </span>
    <div id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id56:j_id57:j_id59:j_id160"></div>
</form>
```

`action="/knowledgebase/FileNotFound"` why does this link appears like destination URL for form? If I click on this form I'm get redirected on *404 error* page and see *401 Unauthorized* error in FireBug console for **http://myhost.force.com/knowledgebase/FileNotFound**

Comment: Can you post your visualforce and controller?

Comment: Doug, it's absolutely like in example above, except that in my case form is placed not on the page, but in the component.

Comment: It would still be useful for you to post a code sample that we can perhaps take and reproduce the issue. I could do this from what you've said, but just to be sure, it would be better if you can provide a code sample. In the meantime, apex:form cannot exist in a component, you should get an error on save, if not, try putting a apex:form tag on your vf page that uses your component (obviously with your component within that).

Comment: Andrew, thanks a lot! Looks like this is a root of issue. I didn't get any error when saved component with `apex:form`. After moving code from component to the page everything works. Could you please provide link to doc where this rule is defined? I can't find any reference to it.